# what is the effect of storing a lot of row in a mysql table (maybe more than one bilion) for a search engine?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I want to store more than one billion row in my search engine db.

I think when the number of rows going upper than a number we experiencing pressure in fetching queries to introduce result.

What is the best way to store a lot of data in mysql? one approach that I tested was split data to more tables instead of using just one table, but it make me to write some complicated methods to fetching the data from different tables in each search.

What is the effect of storing a lot of row in a mysql table (maybe more than one billion) for a search engine and what we can do to increasing number of rows without negative effects on fetch speed ?

I think google and other search engines use a technique to render some query sets and produce results based on a ranking algorithm, is this true?

I experienced data storage in splitted tables for better efficiency and it was good but complicated for fetching.

Please give me a technical approach to store more data in one table with minimum resource usage.

Comment: A billion rows in a database isn't all that many really. As the answers below say, proper indexing is going to help a lot.

Comment: Thank you so much dear @Dave. I try to find out how to do a good proper indexing in my mysql database. do you have a good tutorial link to do proper indexing?

Comment: "Search"?  FULLTEXT?  Numeric?  Other?

Comment: Dear @RickJames, I'm not sure about search, the purpose is just store heading tags. Is this possible to search in mysql json stored columns ?

Comment: @WilliamJohnson - What is a "heading tag"?  If you have a tentative schema (`CREATE TABLEs`), let's see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any database, the primary methods for accessing large tables are:

- Proper indexing
- Partitioning (i.e. storing single tables in multiple "files").

These usually suffice and should be sufficient for your data.

There are some additional techniques that depend on the data and database.  Two that come to mind are:

- Vertical/column partitioning:  storing separate columns in separate table spaces.
- Data compression for wide columns.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. l think Vertical/column partitioning technique seems to be good. but if we separate every column, our algorithm is going to be a little complicated. how we can compress our data in mysql can you explain that a little please?

Comment: @WilliamJohnson . . . I don't think MySQL supports vertical partitioning, so there would be a fair amount of overhead in using it.  In databases that do, it is invisible to the queries.  The storage engine knows how to bring the data together.

Comment: Dear @ Gordon Linoff, do you have any tutorial about proper indexing and partitioning in mysql database structure design (youtube link or any tutorial article)?

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't see your comment before asking my previous question, my question is just about proper indexing.

Comment: I don't think there is much benefit from partitioning, whether vertical or horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily store billions of data in MySQL and for fast handling, you should do proper indexing, and the splitting of tables is mainly for normalization by column-wise distribution, not for row-wise distribution.
This earlier link may help:[How to store large number of records in MySql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22908895/7979331)

Comment: Very hopeful answer, thank you dear @aksr. do you have any tutorial related to proper indexing in mysql (youtube or any article link). I checked your link, thank you for the link. table splitting technique is not useful ?

Comment: Here is one indexing Cookbook: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql